# Get Value using Key from Array - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want get a specific value from key inside an array like that

```
   $scope.result = [
{

    "key":"logo_big",
    "value":"/assets/images/aaa.jpg"
    },
    {
    "key":"logo_small",
    "value":"/assets/images/logo94x57Bis.png"
    },
    {
    "key":"project_name",
    "value":"Company"
    },
    {
    "key":"support_email",
    "value":"dev@gmail.com"
    }
    ];
```

How can I get a value of 'logo_big'?

```
$scope.result['logo_big']
```

return undefined

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using a library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com), which as an awesome [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#find) function, which could be used in your example as `var item = _.find($scope.result, {key: 'logo_big'});`

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj = $scope.results.filter(e => e.key == "logo_big")[0];
```

See the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @SamIam this code is valid ES2015, i.e. the not so newer JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array to find the element which has the given key.

Or, if Array.find() is supported on your system:

```
var item = $scope.result.find(function(element) {
    return element.key === 'logo_big';
});
return item && item.value;
```

A less optimal solution is to use filter:

```
var item = $scope.result.filter(function(element) {
    return element.key === 'logo_big';
})[0];
return item && item.value;
```

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate, rather than providing an answer to something that's a fairly old and well-solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array first and each array item is a object so if you want to access you have to follow below

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.result.length; i++) 
{
  if ($scope.result[i]["key"] == "logo_big") 
  {
   alert("found value");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in angular way, use angular.foreach and check for object's key

```
angular.forEach($scope.result, function(obj) {
      if (obj.key == "logo_big") {
        $scope.resultObj = obj.value;
        alert($scope.resultObj);
      }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("listController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'StackOverflow';
  $scope.result = [{
    "key": "logo_big",
    "value": "/assets/images/aaa.jpg"
  }, {
    "key": "logo_small",
    "value": "/assets/images/logo94x57Bis.png"
  }, {
    "key": "project_name",
    "value": "Company"
  }, {
    "key": "support_email",
    "value": "dev@gmail.com"
  }];

  angular.forEach($scope.result, function(obj) {
    if (obj.key == "logo_big") {
      $scope.resultObj = obj.value;
    }
  });

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="listController">
  <h3>Enter an ID</h3>
   <h1> {{resultObj}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```